# How can I make Vue Sortable work on table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sortablejs

I have an issue with this library. First of all, to test the library, I made a simple example work with ul and li tags. It was straightforward. Then, I needed to do a table, and when converting my example to a table it didn't work.

Table is showed but I cannot move any row.

I'm using the cdn way.

I think is something what I missing.

html

```
<div id='app-example-drag' >
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Sport</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <draggable v-model="list" tag="tbody">
          <tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.name">
            <td scope="row">{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sport }}</td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </table>
</div>
```

js

```
                    Vue.component('draggable',vuedraggable);

applicationExample = new Vue({
  el: '#app-example-drag',
  display: "Table",
  order: 8,
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        { id: 1, name: "Abby", sport: "basket" },
        { id: 2, name: "Brooke", sport: "foot" },
        { id: 3, name: "Courtenay", sport: "volley" },
        { id: 4, name: "David", sport: "rugby" }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0Luhd694/3/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem. I think it has something to with recent version. Replace the draggable element with a tbody and make is='draggable'.

```
<div id='app-example-drag' >
  <table class='table'>
      <thead>
          <tr><th scope='col'>description</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody tag='tbody' v-model='lista1' is='draggable' group='items'>
          <tr v-for='item in lista1' :key='item.id'>
           <td scope='row'>{{item.description}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqf64kdx/